# Rename variables of multiple data_frames using a lookup table (or data dictionary)

Tags: r, purrr

I have multiple similar datasets (e.g. one for each year), but the variable naming convention is different for each one. This is a pretty simple task for a single dataframe, but I'm looking for an approach scalable to many datasets.

My approach has been to use a master lookup table or "data dictionary" so that all the data could be merged into a single dataframe. 
I've abstracted down to a simple example.

My preferred workflow is generally to store data in a 'list-column' and use `purrr` to perform the same task on each dataset.

***Question- My current solution is below, but I'd like to know:***

1. Is there a way to do this using a single master lookup table? (my failed attempt at the end of the example)
2. Is there a better solution/general workflow for this common problem that someone could suggest.

*Here is the lookup table I"ll use:*

```
lookup_table <-
  tribble(~Var, ~newvarname,
          "mpg", "mpg",
          "cyl", "cyl",
          "CYLINDERS", "cyl",
          "disp", "disp",
          "DISPLACEMENT", "disp",
          "hp", "hp",
          "HORSEPOWER", "hp")
```

*example data with mismatched variable names:*

```
mt_list <- 
  data_frame(testcase = 1:3,
             data =list(rename(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), CYLINDERS = "cyl"), 
                        rename(tail(mtcars[, 1:4]), HORSEPOWER = "hp"), 
                        rename(mtcars[13:18, 1:4], DISPLACEMENT = "disp")),
             lookup = list(lookup_table, lookup_table, lookup_table))
```

If you run this code, you can see why this won't work...the datasets don't share common variable names.

```
mt_list %>% 
  select(data) %>% 
  unnest() %>% head(5)

# A tibble: 5 x 7
    mpg CYLINDERS  disp    hp   cyl HORSEPOWER DISPLACEMENT
  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1  21           6   160   110    NA         NA           NA
2  21           6   160   110    NA         NA           NA
3  22.8         4   108    93    NA         NA           NA
4  21.4         6   258   110    NA         NA           NA
5  18.7         8   360   175    NA         NA           NA
```

**The best solution I've found so far:**

```
mt_list <- 
  mt_list %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(.$data, mt_list$lookup, 
                     ~setNames(.x, .y$newvarname[match(names(.x), .y$Var)])))
```

which can then be unnested.

When I try to use a single Master lookup table, I get an error. I've solved it above just by copying the table to each row of the dataframe, but this could lead to issues down the road.

```
mt_list %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(.$data, lookup_table, 
                     ~setNames(.x, .y$varname[match(names(.x), .y$Var)])))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: `.x` (3) and `.y` (2) are different lengths.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your datasets are similar (i.e. same number of variables and column order), the following should do the job:

```
# create a list of data frames (no need for your complicated nested structure)
dfs <- mt_list$data # alternatively: dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# store the desired variable names
varnames <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp")

# set the variable names across the list of data frames
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(x) setNames(x, varnames))
```

If the order of variables is not the same across data frames, you can sort columns by their name before applying the above-given solution:

```
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(x) x[ , order(names(x))])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. this doesn't quite get me where I need to get, using a lookup table though. I didn't go into detail about the actual data structure, but storing the data in the manner I've listed helps keep the data better organized, with filename as a variable with data on same row. It's a matter of preference but it helps programmatically to keep it that way rather than loose objects.

Comment: this answer did push me to the following solution: `map(mt_list$data, lookup_table = lookup_table, .f = function(x, lookup_table) {
  varnames = lookup_table$newvarname[match(names(x), lookup_table$Var)]
  setNames(x, varnames)})`

Comment: These answers are parallel. It was just a bit hard to understand what you need without details. Glad that this was helpful!